# Increase curvature of connecting arcs

Tags: graphviz, neato

Consider:

```
digraph D {
    0[pos="0,0!"]
    1[pos="0,5!"]
    0 -> 1[label=0.25]
    1 -> 0[label=0.50]
}
```

Rendered under `neato` [engine](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/), this gives:

[image]

Is there a way to increase/control the curvature of the connecting arcs so that the rendering is something like the hand-drawn annotations below:

[image]

---

Edited to add: While I don't have to stick with `neato`, it is important in my application that the node `pos` coordinate values be upheld.

Comment: 1. does it have to be neato (not dot)?  2. is it important to have pinned (set)  the node pos values?

Comment: 1. It does not have to be neato. 2. It **is** important to have nodes pinned to their pos values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[there may be better ways, but edges are pretty hard to wrangle]
This solution requires `neato -n` (see https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords) and (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/)
Different versions of **neato** seem to produce different results when previous answer is input.  This input file should work with older & newer versions of **neato**.

```
digraph D {
    // next  lines from the Graphviz FAQ
    overlap=false
    splines=true
    
    0[pos="0,0!"]
    1[pos="0,5!"] 
    // stick an invisible node in the middle, to force the edges out
    half [pos="0,2.5!" width=1.1 height=1  style=invis]  
    0:nw -> 1:sw [label=0.25]
    1:se -> 0:ne [label=0.50]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: This works perfectly with one change. I had to set scale = 1. With scale = 72 as indicated in your answer, the graph appears very "distant". You also helped me in my previous question about scaling. The term "distant" is the same as from that thread.

Comment: I am trying this on the online graphviz engine. When I add other nodes, the two separate directed arcs seem to merge into a single bidirectional arc. See gif https://imgur.com/a/1a7UQEl
You will have to click on the gif to see the animation. Could you let me know what could be going on? Also, I tried using the command line. That gives rise to a completely different output. See https://imgur.com/a/nSD9qRA
Could you please help?